# applying non procedure and non object error

Tags: fibonacci, oz

```
declare
fun {Factorial N}
   local FactorialAux in
      fun {FactorialAux N Product}
     if N == 0 then Product
     else {FactorialAux N-1 {fibo N}|Product}
     end
      end
      {FactorialAux N nil}
   end
end

fun {fibo N}
   if N==1 then 1
   else if N==2 then 1
    else {fibo N-1}+{fibo N-2}
    end
   end
end

{Browse {Factorial 3}}
```

My code prints the list of fibonacci number.If N =4 then it prints first four fibonacci number list
This is my code in which i am getting the error stated in the heading of question.
Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Variables must start with an uppercase letter in Oz. Procedure and function names are always variables, so they must also start with an uppercase letter.

Your function `fibo` should be called `Fibo`. And of course, all calls to `fibo` must be fixed, too.